# Emacs Can't type space right after Javascript keyword

Tags: javascript, emacs

I'm on a Mac Big Sur running Emacs 27.2 and use lsp-mode for all programming languages. Only for Javascript, when I type a keyword and hit space, the cursor snaps right back. So say I type `import` and hit space, I expect this `import`  i.e. a space after the keyword.

However what happens is when I press space, the cursor moves one space to the right and snaps right back. So `import foo` becomes `importfoo`.This happens only in Javascript and without me saving the file.

This makes it so I can't use emacs for Javascript but it's find with Elixir, Python etc.

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, then bisect your init file, to find the culprit. (And it seems like your recipe to repro the problem is incomplete.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was `aggressive-indent-mode`. I had it turned on for `js2-mode` and that was the cause so I just commented it out. Someone helped me out with the solution on the lsp-mode issue tracker on github.

Comment: Since posting this, I've come across an issue on the `aggressive-indent-mode` github page which one might want to [track](https://github.com/Malabarba/aggressive-indent-mode/issues/127)